# Have a popup window appear as a mouse over that references a bookmark in a Tikiwiki

Tags: bookmarks, tiki-wiki

I am working on a Tikiwiki for work and am trying to find a way that makes a popup box appear when mousing over certain words but I want the info inside the box to be referencing a bookmark so that the info is always up to date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MOUSEOVER plugin to create the popup box:

{MOUSEOVER(label="Hover over this text to see my message.")}Hello over there. It's fine!{MOUSEOVER}

See the docs (http://doc.tiki.org/PluginMouseover) for details.